# How Can I Reduce "When" Statement in XSLT

Tags: xslt

Hello I am writing a XSLT statement where I need to implement 1500 conditional statements like -

```
<xsl:when test="ID = '51'">
  <br>
  <xsl:text>background: url('rightcolumn_seniorliv.jpg') no-repeat;</xsl:text>
  <br>
</xsl:when>
<br>
<xsl:when test="ID = '52'">
  <br>
  <xsl:text>background: url('rightcolumn_seniorliv.jpg') no-repeat;</xsl:text>
  <br>
</xsl:when>
```

If i write statement like this way then my pages will be very slow. How can i reduce my code and write this statement in a smart way?

Comment: is it always the exact same picture?

Comment: Why do you have to use the ID's to filter on?

Comment: Bkz based on Id i want to load different images in background

Comment: @user499365 - If I understand correctly you have some big map between a test ID and an image, correct? Any chance we can see some more of the map, especially the otherwise? Also what is the general rule for what image is set to the background for which test? i.e., what's the requirements you are working from?

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:variable name="idlist">
  <ids>
    <id>50</id>
    <id>59</id>
    <id>66</id>
    ...
  </ids>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="idk" match="id" use="."/>

<xsl:when test="key('idk', ID, $idlist)">...
```

This is XSLT 2.0 but can be adapted to work with 1.0.

Comment: Your solution is looks good to me lets try. I am scared if my server again overload for lot of statement.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see all your cases, but if the pattern from your first two continues and you want that same 'rightcolumn_seniorliv.jpg' for IDs 51 thru 1551 then

```
<xsl: when test="ID&gt;'50' and ID&lt;'1552'">
```

---

it sounds like these ID cases are going well beyond logic and into the data realm.  i obviously dont know anything about your app, but perhaps an ID to imagename mapping somewhere (probably database) would be in order.  depending on what process generates the XML file (the first one, before XSLT transformation), you might want to just set the image name (or lack thereof) explicitly thru this mapping.  then lose the `when` all together

Comment: Thanks for your answer but ids are Random not by serial Like ID = 51,550,345,458,943

Comment: If i put it this way then it will work faster? <xsl:when test="ID = '3' or '51' or '59' or '66' or '69' or '70' or '74' or '546' or '60' or '63' or '67' or '68' or '140' or '75' or '77' or '147' or '115' or '149' or '92' or '169' or '170' or '171' or '549' or '172' or '519' or '1260' or '173' or '144' or '146' or '46' or '40' or '39' or '43'">
<xsl:text>background: url('rightcolumn_seniorliv.jpg') no-repeat;</xsl:text> 
</xsl:when>

Comment: @user499365: `contains(' 3 51 59 66 69 70 74 546 60 63 67 68 140 75 77 147 115 149 92 169 170 171 549 172 519 1260 173 144 146 46 40 39 43 ',concat(' ',ID,' '))`